# I deleted network-manager and now can't access internet

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I recently deleted the `network-manager` from Linux Mint by running `sudo apt remove --purge network-manager`. I am unable to access the internet via WiFi now. I have no clue what to do next, anyone have any suggestions?

OS: Linux Mint

Edit:

Output of `apt list wpasupplicant` :

```
wpasupplicant/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.4-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [installed] 
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

And the output of `ip link` :

```
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode 
DORMANT group default qlen 1000 link/ether ... brd ...`
```

Note: I intentionally left out the output of `enp2s0` and `lo`.

Comment: Network-manager is a front end. EITHER Can you connect to the Internet from the command line? e.g. https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/18/connect-to-wifi-network-from-command-line-in-linux/ OR if you still have the CD/USB and can return it as a repository you should be able to reinstall network-manager

Comment: I tried reinstalling from CD ROM after adding back as a repository and it still wouldn't reinstall... I will try connecting via terminal but it didn't work before.

Comment: I tried connecting from terminal and my wireless interface `wlp3s0` wouldn't connect...

Comment: Did you edit your sources.list to add the CD back?

Comment: I re-added it via the Package Manager, and I double checked `/etc/apt/sources.list` and it contained this: `deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.3 _Sylvia_ - Release amd64 20171127]/ xenial contrib main non-free`

Comment: What is the output of `apt list wpasupplicant`  and `ip link` please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/411435/edit)?

Comment: To connect use `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp3s0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "your_SSID" your_password)` then `sudo dhclient wlp3s0` , change `your_SSID` and `your_password` with yours.

Comment: What if my networks SSID has a space in the name? For example `bobs burgers`?

Comment: Double quoting your SSID `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp3s0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "bobs burgers" PASSWORD-HERE)`

Comment: It says `wpa_passphrase: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just type `sudo wpa_supplicant` in the terminal if you get (the first line) `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant` i will write an answer. Or Try the above command as ROOT.

Comment: Yes I got successfully initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file :

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

with the following content:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
       ssid="Your SSID"
       psk="your_passphrase"
       }
```

Save then run the following commands:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp3s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
sudo dhclient wlp3s0
```

the `dhclient` command is used to get an IP through dhcp , it can be replaced with:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.150 dev wlp3s0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

Replace `192.168.1.1` with your gateway and  `192.168.1.150` with the desired IP address .

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This solved all my issues and my computer is now connected back to the internet!!!

Comment: Update: After a good bit of use, this fix is no longer working... When I re-run everything it hangs on `sudo dhclient wlp3s0`... Any suggestions?

Comment: @NerdOfCode see my update .

Comment: Life saver!  Thank you @GAD3R.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect via a wired (cable) connection to the internet.
   Use the [DHCP version here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html) (iface eth0 inet dhcp).
2. Update and upgrade apt via internet (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`).
3. Install network-manager again (`apt-get install network-manager`).

Comment: Ethernet is not an option....

Answer (score 1):

@GAD3R 's solution is great. But I noticed that it would be good if you use
`sudo iw dev` to decide what device you have first and then use his commands. Otherwise, you will have "No such device"